# Definition/properties of NFA extended transition function

Tags: regular-languages, automata, finite-automata

I am trying to prove by induction that if

$$\hat\delta_d(q_0, w) = \hat\delta_n(q_0, w)$$

I know by practicing inductive proofs of the $\hat\delta$ for DFAs, that on the basis of the definition of $\hat\delta_d$

1. for any $q \in Q$, $\hat\delta(q, \epsilon) = q$
2. for any $q \in Q$ and $a \in $ the language of the DFA,  $\hat\delta(\delta(q, y), a)$
3. $\hat\delta(q, ax) = \hat\delta(q_1, x)$ where $a_1 = \delta(q,a)$

Does the extended transition function also have these properties? Does it have other definitions/properties?

For reference, $\hat\delta_d$ refers to the extended transition function of DFAs and $\hat\delta_n$ refers to the extended transition function of NFAs.

Comment: Kindly clarify what you mean specifically by $\hat\delta_d$,$\hat\delta_n$,$\hat\delta$. Are all of them transition functions for DFA's or does some of them refer to NFA's?

Comment: This question is unanswerable because you've not defined your notation and because you've only written half of what you're trying to prove: "If X=Y, then _what_?" You could attempt to prove that "If it is raining, sensible people use umbrellas" but it makes no sense to attempt to prove "If it is raining".

Comment: @DavidRicherby not trying to get help with the proof! Just trying to find properties of the extended transition function of NFAs. I mentioned the proof as context. If it is distracting, I will delete it.

Comment: Also, bullet 2 doesn't make any sense; something seems missing.  Did you mean to say that $\hat{\delta}(\delta(q,y),a)$ is equal to something?  If so, what?

Comment: When you say the language of the DFA, do you perhaps mean the alphabet?  ($\Sigma$)  That's not the same thing.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2662696/14578, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/88478/755.   Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.